Winforms WebBrowser control not rendering correctly on Windows 11
I have a .NET 4.8 Winforms application that has been deployed under Windows 10 and uses the Winforms WebBrowser control. On this control, I am displaying a page containing simple HTML which makes reference to a CSS style sheet. It renders perfectly as expected.
When I attempt to deploy the same app under Windows 11, the same page renders incorrectly, seemingly missing the stylesheets - the text shows but it is positioned and formatted incorrectly and the background is missing (it is defined within a  HTML tag).
Interestingly, have made the WebBrowser control point to https://html5test.co/ and the version & capabilities of the working (Win10) and non-working (Win11) versions of the browser are exactly the same (it's reporting "You are using Internet Explorer 11.0 on Windows 8" and score is 316/594 points on both systems). This seems to indicate that either something in the HTML source is the problem (I can't see why as it's pointing to the same internet-based source) or that something on the O/S itself is missing something or preventing it from rendering correctly.
I have looked extensively through StackOverflow and there seems to be some discussion around the compatibility of the WebBrowser control through various Windows versions. Unfortunately none of the suggestions so far has helped me resolve the issue, leading me to believe many of these articles are now obsolete (most are from before 2015).
Are there any suggestions that could help me identify what the issue is with rendering the page and how to resolve it?

The WebBrowser Control has been deprecated, a while ago. Use WebView2 instead

Thanks, @jimi, but would you know why there is a difference in rendering since I know the WebBrowser control works for my requirements. My app is in production and I'd prefer to not make significant changes if I can help it.

The WebBrowser Control uses Internet Explorer (in quirks, IE7 compatibility mode, if not otherwise specified). As you know, IE is deprecated, won't get security updates anymore, so the rendering engine's access to external resources is limited. You can try to in-line the CSS. No guarantee it's going to work as expected in any case. Replacing it with WebView2 is not that complicated, if you're not accessing the underlying DOM (e.g., using the old HtmlElement COM objects)

Here's an example of the initialization procedure of WebView2. Not much else you have to do, if it's used to just show HTML content

Thanks, @Jimi. I am trying WebView out and it seems like there's a bit of code I will need to change. Straight off, it looks like the "ScrollBarsEnabled" property is no longer there and I will need to do some JS hacks to make it work. That will require lots of testing for a prod app. I'll check out your link to see if I can tweak IE to make WebBrowser work. That's my ideal solution as I believe it might be the quickest & most reliable with my given constraints.

Yep, without external, dedicated packages (that exist), you access the DOM through JavaScript (with document.documentElement.style.overflow in this case)

Hi @Jimi, I've spent the last day digging myself into a hole with WebView2 unfortunately. It seems like there's many additional dlls and runtimes to include in the deployment. My app can be deployed on alternate O/S's in its current state but probably not with the additional native DLLs. It's certainly not straight forward so I'm back to seeing what I can do with the existing WebBrowser control.

That's true, the first time you have to package WebView2, the procedure may seem somewhat overwhelming. To note that the run-time is included in Windows 10 and 11, so most of the time you don't need to package everything. The generated directory structure is also unneeded, when you specify, at run-time, the User's storage folder and the WebView2 Loader folder. But, yes, it's still not as straightforward as just adding the component to a Form -- Try the Registry settings shown in one of the links and, as mentioned, try to in-line the CSS / styles / JavaScripts

In case it's needed in the future: Distribute your app and the WebView2 Runtime

Thanks for your suggestions, @Jimi. I have added some more details about my investigation so far in the original question. It seems that both instances of WebBrowser have exactly the same capability on both systems so there's something else at play here.

It appears that the problem is not related specifically to the Windows version but rather how the page is rendered under different systems. As noted on this and this StackOverflow question, the answer is to put the following code in the <head> tag of the HTML to resolve the rendering issue:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

